# Flutter: Rect.fromCenter not drawing square where I click

Tags: flutter, dart, canvas, widget, sprite

I am trying to draw a square when I click on the screen. I have the drawing logic working and I can do it onclick but for some reason it's drawing the squares somewhat randomly. Ideally I want it to be drawn from the point of click. Wherever I click should be the center of the new square. Here is what currently happens when I click the iOS simulator.

[image]

I was trying to use `event.pointerEvent.localPosition.dx` and `...dy` where `event` is of type `SpriteBoxEvent`. I am using them to create an `Offset` instance which will be used in `Rect.fromCenter` as I figured that would be best to use with my pointer coordinates since I wanted them to be the center of the square.

Below is my code for my `SpriteSquare` widget and the `handleAdd` function that is in the parent widget, `MySpriteGame` (minus the imports as those aren't causing any issues).

[Here](https://github.com/macro6461/flutter_game_engines) is the full GitHub repo.

**sprite_square.dart**

```
class SpriteSquare extends NodeWithSize {
  
  Color color;
  Function handler;
  double left;
  double top;

  SpriteSquare(size, this.color, this.handler, this.top, this.left) : super(size){
    userInteractionEnabled = true;
  }

  @override handleEvent(SpriteBoxEvent event) {
    handler(event);
    return true;
  }

  @override
    Future<void> paint(Canvas canvas) async {
      canvas.drawRect(
        Rect.fromLTWH(left, top, size.height, size.width),
        Paint()..color = color
      );
    }
}
```

**handleAdd**

```
handleAdd(SpriteBoxEvent event) {
    final _whitesquare = SpriteSquare(
      const Size(50.0, 50.0), 
      const Color(0xFFFFFFFF), 
      handleRemoveSelf, 
      Offset(event.pointerEvent.localPosition.dx, event.pointerEvent.localPosition.dy)
    );
    _background.addChild(_whitesquare);
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: I will take a look if you were able to provide the complete working project (on GitHub or somewhere else).

Comment: @Amir_P just updated the code and added the repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating your background `SpriteSquare` with wrong sizes and then you are adding other `SpriteSquare` with positions computed from touch event positions transformed to `SpriteWidget`'s local position which can be smaller or bigger then your background `SpriteSquare`. Here is how I solved it:

1. Removed `SingleChildScrollView` from your `MyHomePage` widget.
2. Changed `LayoutBuilder` position in widget tree. So the final `MyHomePage`'s build function body is like this:

```
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(widget.title),
    ),
    body: Center(child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (ctx, constrain
      return Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'Select Game Engine',
            ),
            DropdownButton<String>(
              value: _whichEngine,
              icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
              iconSize: 24,
              elevation: 16,
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple)
              underline: Container(
                height: 2,
                color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
              ),
              onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  _whichEngine = newValue!;
                });
              },
              items: <String>[
                'Flame',
                'Quill',
                'SpriteWidget',
                'Feathers',
                'Unity'
              ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: value,
                  child: Text(value),
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: LayoutBuilder(
                builder: (context, constraints) {
                  final size =
                      Size(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.m
                  if (_whichEngine == 'Flame') {
                    return GameWidget(
                      game: MyFlameGame(),
                    );
                  } else if (_whichEngine == 'SpriteWidget') {
                    return MySpriteGame(size: size);
                  } else {
                    return MySpriteGame(size: size);
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
          ]);
    })));
```

3. Fixed wrong order of height and width in `SpriteSquare`. So this is the body of paint function in `SpriteSquare` now:

```
canvas.drawRect(
  Rect.fromLTWH(left, top, size.height, size.width),
  Paint()..color = color
);
```

4. Changed `MySpriteGame` to take a size from it's parent and construct background with that size and tweaked values in `handleAdd`:

```
class MySpriteGame extends StatelessWidget {
  final _background;

  MySpriteGame({Key? key, required Size size})
      : _background = SpriteSquare(size, const Color(0xFF000000), () {}, 0, 0),
        super(key: key) {}

  handleAdd(SpriteBoxEvent event) {
    final _whitesquare = SpriteSquare(
      const Size(50.0, 50.0),
      const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
      handleRemoveSelf,
      event.pointerEvent.localPosition.dy - 25,
      event.pointerEvent.localPosition.dx - 25,
    );
    _background.addChild(_whitesquare);
    return true;
  }

  handleRemoveSelf(SpriteBoxEvent event) {
    print('hello');
    return true;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _background.handler = handleAdd;
    return SpriteWidget(_background);
  }
}
```

With these changes it's working correctly now.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This was really helpful.

Comment: You're welcome @MattCroak

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, I would appreciate the bounty :D @MattCroak

Comment: My mistake, I assumed if I accepted the answer the bounty would be awarded to you @Amir_P

Comment: Thanks! @MattCroak